# Select average rating from another datatable

Tags: sql, select

I have 3 data tables.

In the entries data table I have entries with ID (entryId as primary key).

I have another table called EntryUsersRatings in there are multiple entries that have entryId field and a rating value (from 1 to 5).
 (ratings are stored multiple times for one entryId).
Columns: ratingId (primary key), entryId, rating (integer value).

In the third data table I have translations of entries in the first table (with entryId, languageId and title - translation).

What I would like to do is select all entries from first data table with their titles (by language ID).
On a top of that I want average rating of each entry (which can be stored multiple times) that is stored in EntryUsersRatings.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT entries.entryId, EntryTranslations.title, AVG(EntryUsersRatings.rating) AS AverageRating
FROM entries 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        EntryTranslations ON entries.entryId = EntryTranslations.entryId AND EntryTranslations.languageId = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        EntryUsersRatings ON entries.entryId = EntryUsersRatings.entryId
      WHERE entries.isDraft=0
    GROUP BY title, entries.entryId
```

isDraft is just something that means that entries are not stored with all information needed (just incomplete data - irrelevant for our case here).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: my solution gives me null values for rating.
Edit1: this query is working perfectly OK, I was looking into wrong database.
We also came to another solution, which gives us the same result (I hope someone will find this useful):

```
    SELECT entries.entryId, COALESCE(x.EntryUsersRatings, 0) as averageRating
    FROM entries  
    LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT rr.entryId, AVG(rating) AS entryRating 
    FROM EntryUsersRatings  rr 
    GROUP BY rr.entryId) x ON x.entryId = entries.entryId
```

Comment: What is the problem with the query you posted? Any errors? Not the desired results???

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that.
Rating with my solution is always null.

Comment: @CyberHawk Why there is a ` AND t.languageId = 1` in  the first join?

Comment: languageId specifies which translation I want returned as title (since EntryTranslations contains translations for various languages. 1 = just specific ID of one of the languages).
Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: What happen when LEFT JOIN changed to INNER JOIN?

Comment: @Prasanna: tried to change to INNER JOIN with all variants (first, second, both) unfortunately no desired result :(

Comment: Can you post some sample data for the tables? Maybe even set up an example on SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Are you sure you have related records in EntryUsersRatings and EntryTranslations ?

Comment: Sure (sorry, don't know how to format data, so it is more user frindly displayed)!

Result my solution gives me for entryId 39:
entryId - title - AverageRating
39 - SomeTitle - NULL

What is stored in entryUserRatings:
entryUserRatingId - entryId - userId - rating - ratingDate
14 - 39 - 8 - 5 - 2012-10-22 -11:23:57.503

Comment: Strange! but you can set null values as zero before AVG, AVG(ISNULL(EntryUsersRatings.rating,0))

Comment: I have done this and now (as expected) I get 0 instead of NULL

Comment: NULL returns when you do not have related records. However I think you got what you expected!

Comment: We have figured out, that I was looking into wrong database.
The query, that I posted actually works just fine.
Thank to all for your comments - you knew that the query was OK.
So: the problem was between chair and the keyboard :D

Answer (score 0):

@CyberHawk:  as you are using left outer join with entries, your result will give all records from left table and matching record with your join condition from right table. but for unmatching records it will give you a null value .

check out following link for the deta:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: But, I don't get any results from right table ... this is source of my problem.

Comment: try using following query 

SELECT e. entryId,et. Title,AVG(eu. Rating) FROM entries  LEFT OUTER JOIN    EntryUsersRatings eu ON eu.entryId = e.entryId
LEFT OUTER JOIN EntryTranslations et ON et. entryId= e.entryId
WHERE et. languageId = 1  AND e.isDraft=0 GROUP BY   eu. Rating,  e. entryId, et. Title